# host header in iis7

Tags: iis-7

i have following doubts while creating new sites in iis7

1. what should be value of host header in site binding. should it match with domain name ?
2. should website name and host header be same?

Answer (score 1):

If your websites are `www.example.com` and `blogs.example.com`, your host headers should be `www.example.com` and `blogs.example.com`.

If you want any traffic to a name that resolves to an IP address on your server to go to a specific site, then don't put a host header on that site.  (E.g. have a host header for `blogs.example.com` but not for `www.example.com`.)